# How to adapt this example function to Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, onclick, coffeescript

I want to rewrite this code to Backbone.js, how should I do that?

app/assets/javascripts/views/plots/plots_index.js.coffee

```
class App.Views.PlotsIndex extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['plots/index']

  events:
    'submit #new_plot': 'createPlot'

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, this)
    @collection.on('add', @appendPlot, this)

  render: =>
    $(@el).html(@template())
    @collection.each(@appendPlot)
    this

  appendPlot: (plot) =>
    view = new App.Views.Plot(model: plot)
    @$('#all_plots').append(view.render().el)

  createPlot: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    attributes = name: $('#new_plot_name').val()
    @collection.create attributes,
      wait: true
      success: ->  $('#new_plot')[0].reset()
      error: @handleError
```

app/assets/templates/plots/index.jst.eco

```
<textarea class="input" id="new_plot_name" name="name" rows="5"  onClick="if(this.value == 'Type something') { this.value = ''; }">Type something</textarea> 
<input class="generate_button col2" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I want to put the function from onClick into the view code, but can't quite figure it. I tried things like this, but no luck:

```
    events:
        'click #new_plot_name' : 'clear'

    clear: =>
    if @$('#new_plot_name').value == 'Type something'
        @$('#new_plot_name').value = ''
```

What would be the way to do it, so I can do something like:

```
 <textarea class="input" id="new_plot_name" name="name" rows="5"  onClick="<%= @clear(this) %>">Type something</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is in your `clear` method.

```
clear: =>
  if @$('#new_plot_name').value == 'Type something'
    @$('#new_plot_name').value = ''
```

When you say `x = @$('#new_plot_name')`, you get a jQuery object in `x`. jQuery objects generally don't have `value` properties the way DOM objects do; if you want to work with the value of a form element that's wrapped in a jQuery object, you want to use the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
clear: =>
  if @$('#new_plot_name').val() == 'Type something'
    @$('#new_plot_name').val('')
```

Then drop the `onClick` attribute from your template:

```
<textarea class="input" id="new_plot_name" name="name" rows="5">Type something</textarea>
```

CoffeeScript (`@clear(this)`) won't work there, neither `@` nor `this` would be what you want in that context, and `clear` doesn't take an object argument anyway. Besides, this is Backbone so the events should be hooked up through the view's `events`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gfK4L/

---

That said, people do use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move around inside forms so you probably want to use a focus event (not click) to remove your placeholder and a blur event to put it back.

You should also be using a [`placeholder`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html#textarea.attrs.placeholder) attribute for this sort of thing; if you need to support non-HTML5 browsers then there are lots of shims and plugins that will work better than your `clear` method. Placeholder behavior is surprising tricky to get right, for example you'll probably be submitting a lot of forms with `name` coming through as `'Type something'` because you're not checking that they really did type something in your submit handler.

Also, there's no need for `$(@el)`, Backbone already supplies a jQuery wrapped `@el` in [`@$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el). And in your `initialize`:

```
initialize: ->
  @collection.on('reset', @render, this)
  @collection.on('add', @appendPlot, this)
```

you don't need to supply the context arguments to `on` since `render` and `appendPlot` are already bound methods, just this should do:

```
initialize: ->
  @collection.on('reset', @render)
  @collection.on('add', @appendPlot)
```